# Make sbt use last downloaded version of akka

Tags: sbt, akka, playframework-2.1

I'm using play 2.1.4 , it has akka-actor_2.10. 
Now i want to use akka-actor_2.10-2.3-M1.

included in build :
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3-M1"

it was successfully downloaded , but project still uses old library , how can i configure it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play 2.1.4 is not compatible with Akka 2.3-M1, you will have to use the Akka version which is pulled in by Play automatically. If you want to use a newer Akka version you will have to use a newer Play version as well.